# multidimension Array to string Conversion

Tags: php, loops

I have two arrays
I wan to convert in two strings..

One Array in first string
2nd Array in Second String

Like this array1 = 5,6,7,8

Like this array2 = 15,16,17,18

Should be in loop no matter How many rows there are

and Soo on..
Help me please I am stuck Here from Many days...

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [ride_id] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 6
            [ride_id] => 6
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [ride_id] => 7
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 8
            [ride_id] => 8
        )


)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 15
            [ride_id] => 15
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 16
            [ride_id] => 16
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 17
            [ride_id] => 17
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 18
            [ride_id] => 18
        )
)
```

Comment: Why don't you create the arrays the way you want them when you're fetching from the database, instead of making 2-dimensional arrays? And use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array()` so you don't get two elements for each column.

Comment: mysqli_fetch_assoc()  Now i am getting single dimension

Comment: But Problem is this I want just values in a string with comma separation..

Comment: In a single string with comma separation                                                                 
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ride_id] => 5
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ride_id] => 6
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ride_id] => 7
        )
)

Comment: I know what you want, isn't that what my answer shows how to do?

Comment: Did you give up?

Comment: No, I got the result, What I want, Thanks for Helping me

Answer (score 1):

Use `array_column()` to get just the `ride_id` element from each nested array, and use `implode()` to combine them into a string.

```
$string1 = implode(',', array_column($array1, 'ride_id'));
$string2 = implode(',', array_column($array2, 'ride_id'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the other answer as I'm a big fan of `array_column`. Another way, if the values are unique, especially if you don't know the column names, is to flatten `array_merge`, make unique `array_unique` and then `implode`:

```
$result1 = implode(',', array_unique(array_merge(...$array1)));
$result2 = implode(',', array_unique(array_merge(...$array2)));
```

Comment: `array_unique()` doesn't seem like a good idea if there are two rows with the same value.

Comment: Yeah, wasn't thinking about that as commonly ids are unique.

Comment: True, it's probably OK in this particular case, but it doesn't generalize well.